# Using MailTo link, Can I send a copy to the sender?

Tags: html, mailto, sender

We've developed a very simple form that once submitted populates an e-mail to send in support tickets. The e-mails currently send to our "support staff" but it would be ideal if we could send a copy to the sender as well. We are using mailto links. is this possible?

For example: Our employee Brad fills out the support ticket form. This launches Brad's native e-mail application filled with the necessary information. Using mailto we already have the support email as a destination. We would like whoever is sending the email to receive a copy as well. How would it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done, at least not from the browser.

While it is possible to encode multiple To addresses (or a CC address) into a `mailto:` URL, you have to know the address you want to send it to in advance.

You *could* write code that watches your support mailbox and copies any incoming email back to the sender, but this would be a terrible idea (not least because it would provide a system for spammers to bounce their spam off your system and back at their targets by using a fake From address).

Almost every email client is configured to keep a copy of any sent email by default anyway. There shouldn't be any need to try to reproduce that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Just include an ask for the senders information in your form. Since you are using a mailto link there's no worry about spam because the sender is sending it using their own email client. Populate the mailto link with the sender's provided information as a bcc.

Check out http://mlto.tk