# React Native - Set email sender in CC

Tags: react-native, email

My code roughly looks as follows

```js
<ListItem onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:' + "destination.address@gmail.com" + '?subject=My Subject&body=' + 'My message')}>
</ListItem>
```

When the user clicks on the component, the share dialog should appear offering all the available email clients and such. As the title says, I would like to add the sender in CC but I have not found a way to know the address such address. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30442715/5924796) suggests there is no way to achieve this. If that is the case, is there any reasonable work around.

Answer (score 0):

Use & operator and add cc like this.

```
<ListItem onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:somethingemail@gmail.com?subject=abcdefg&cc=anotherdude@gmail.com&body=body')}>
```

Comment: "mailto:onecooldude@gmail.com?subject=Hey+Dude.+You're+Cool.&cc=anotherdude@gmail.com,thirddude@gmail.com,fourthdude@gmail.com&bcc=invisibledude@gmail.com,ghost@gmail.com"
Use this for bcc and multple emails

Comment: This doesn't look like it solves the problem of specifically setting the sender in the CC field. It just looks like it sets some addresses